# Inheriting from StreamWriter with smallest possible effort

Tags: c#, mocking, streamwriter

I am using an external library which allows logging using StreamWriter - now I want to add some handling based on the content of the logging. As I want to avoid to loop through the log file, I would like to write a class which inherits from StreamWriter.
What is the best way to inherit from StreamWriter with as few re-implementations of methods/constructors?

Comment: What behavior do you want to change of StreamWriter in your derived class?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know for sure which actual implementation of write is called - my guess is just Write(string). I want to basically keep everything inside the file, but add some handling to check if the logged content contains x. I would prefer this over writing a seperate program which periodically reads the log as it would be more performant.

Comment: Then, use my answer but override all the Write method and place a breakpoint to see what is being called in your specific scenario.

Comment: wrap them all and find out....

Comment: 7 seconds this time. i guess there is only one answer to this question. ;-)

Comment: here is what msdn has to say... [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#notes-to-inheritors)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want to do exactly, but if you only want to inspect what is being written in the stream, you can do this:

```
public class CustomStreamWriter : StreamWriter
{
    public CustomStreamWriter(Stream stream)
        : base(stream)
    {}

    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        //Inspect the value and do something

        base.Write(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just want that you only have to override Write(char) since all other calls to Write ends up there, less effort than overriding every write method. and if you call base.Write() on the other method, you might end up writing the same data more than once (ex: call to write(string)'s base calls write(char))

Answer (score 2):

Determine the constructor the external library use and implement that (or just implement them all) and then you just need to override the write method(s) that your external library uses.

```
public class Class1 : StreamWriter 
{
    public Class1(Stream stream)
        : base(stream)
    {

    }
    public Class1(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
        : base(stream, encoding)
    {

    }
    public Class1(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize)
        : base(stream, encoding, bufferSize)
    {

    }
    public Class1(string path)
        : base(path)
    {

    }
    public Class1(string path, bool append)
        : base(path, append)
    {

    }
    public Class1(string path, bool append, Encoding encoding)
        : base(path, append, encoding)
    {

    }
    public Class1(string path, bool append, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize)
        : base(path, append, encoding, bufferSize)
    {

    }

    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        base.Write(value);
    }
}
```