# In C# how do I get the file position of each text row in an output file (as it is being written)?

Tags: c#, .net

As I write text lines to a temp file, I'd like to store the file position of each line for future random access.

This does NOT work

```
 StreamWriter outFile;

 { ...
          fPos[i++] = outFile.BaseStream.Position;
 }
```

fPos values in the above loop are 0,0,0,...,1024,1024,...2028,2048 etc - i.e. physical positions.

The following DOES work but does away with buffering:

```
 { ...
          outFile.Flush();
          fPos[i++] = outFile.BaseStream.Position;
 }
```

Is there a better way to get the (logical) file position as I go without giving up buffering ?

Comment: You'd have to keep track of it yourself as you write to the file.

Comment: Was about to suggest that...

Comment: you could also write one character at a time, then record position when you write \n.

Comment: In C++/STL seekg seems to do the job (without flushing buffers, I belive).  So I am surprised that you have to do your own bookkeeping in C# - which includes accounting for the newline char(s) in the current environment.

Comment: If you feed your StreamWriter in to a [BufferedStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx) does calling `Flush()` on the StreamWriter stream also flush the BufferedStream stream? If it dose not that could be a solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is small enough to fit in memory, you could have the `StreamWriter` write to a `MemoryStream`. Flush after each line, and get the memory stream's position before writing each line. And when you're done writing the data to the memory stream, copy it to a file.

If the data is larger than will fit in memory, you could use a `MemoryStream` as a buffer, and flush that memory stream to the disk file whenever it fills up. That would take a little bookkeeping, but it wouldn't be too terrible.

Slightly more involved would be to create your own class derived from `BufferedStream` that counts the bytes written to it. Open your stream writer with a buffer size of 0, and have it write to the buffered stream. You could then query the buffered stream for the number of bytes written. Of course, that stream would write to the file stream. So it'd be something like:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(...))
{
    using (var buff = new CustomBufferedStream(fs))
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(buff, encoding))
        {
            ... do your output here
        }
    }
}
```

You might not be able to have a `StreamWriter` buffer size of 0. If that's the case, then you'll have to flush after every line, and you might have to override the custom stream's `Flush` method so that it doesn't automatically flush to the disk file. I don't recall if `StreamWriter.Flush` automatically calls `BaseStream.Flush`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember where this came from exactly, but it has worked pretty well for me in the past.

Replaced reader with writer:

```
/// <summary>
/// A stream writer that allows its current position to be recorded and 
/// changed. This is not generally possible for stream writers, because 
/// of the use buffered reads. 
/// This writer can be used only for text content. Theoretically it can 
/// process any encoding, but was checked only for ANSI and UTF8 If you 
/// want to use this class with any other encoding, please check it.
/// NOT SAFE FOR ASYNC WRITES.
/// </summary>   
public class PositionableStreamWriter : StreamWriter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Out best guess counted position.
    /// </summary>
    private long _position;

    /// <summary>
    /// Guards against e.g. calling "Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count)" 
    /// as part of the implementation of "Write(string value)", which would cause
    /// double counting.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _guardRecursion; 

    public PositionableStreamWriter(string fileName, bool append, Encoding enc)
        : base(fileName, append, enc)
    {
        CommonConstruct();
    }
    public PositionableStreamWriter(Stream stream, Encoding enc)
        : base(stream, enc)
    {
        CommonConstruct();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encoding can really haven't preamble
    /// </summary>        
    private bool CheckPreamble(long lengthBeforeFlush)
    {
        byte[] preamble = this.Encoding.GetPreamble();
        if (this.BaseStream.Length >= preamble.Length)
        {
            if (lengthBeforeFlush == 0)
                return true;
            else // we would love to read, but base stream is write-only.
                return true; // just assume a preamble is there.
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this property to get and set real position in file.
    /// Position in BaseStream can be not right.
    /// </summary>
    public long Position
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set
        {
            this.Flush();
            ((Stream)base.BaseStream).Seek(value, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            _position = value;
        }
    }

    public override void Write(char[] buffer)
    {
        if (buffer != null && !_guardRecursion)
            _position += Encoding.GetByteCount(buffer);
        CallBase(() => base.Write(buffer));
    }
    public override void Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if (buffer != null && !_guardRecursion)
            _position += Encoding.GetByteCount(buffer, index, count);
        CallBase(() => base.Write(buffer, index, count));
    }
    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        if (value != null && !_guardRecursion)
            _position += Encoding.GetByteCount(value);
        CallBase(() => base.Write(value));
    }

    public override void WriteLine()
    {
        if (!_guardRecursion)
            _position += Encoding.GetByteCount(NewLine);
        CallBase(() => base.WriteLine());
    }
    public override void WriteLine(char[] buffer)
    {
        if (buffer != null && !_guardRecursion)
            _position += Encoding.GetByteCount(buffer) + Encoding.GetByteCount(NewLine);
        CallBase(() => base.WriteLine(buffer));
    }
    public override void WriteLine(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        if (buffer != null && !_guardRecursion)
            _position += Encoding.GetByteCount(buffer, index, count) + Encoding.GetByteCount(NewLine);
        CallBase(() => base.WriteLine(buffer, index, count));
    }
    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        if (value != null && !_guardRecursion)
            _position += Encoding.GetByteCount(value) + Encoding.GetByteCount(NewLine);
        CallBase(() => base.WriteLine(value));
    }

    private void CallBase(Action callBase)
    {
        if (_guardRecursion == true)
            callBase();
        else
        {
            try
            {
                _guardRecursion = true;
                callBase();
            }
            finally
            {
                _guardRecursion = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void CommonConstruct()
    {
        var lenghtAtConstruction = BaseStream.Length;
        if (lenghtAtConstruction == 0)
            Flush(); // this should force writing the preamble if a preamble is being written.
        //we need to add length of symbol which is in begin of file and describes encoding of file                                    
        if (CheckPreamble(lenghtAtConstruction))
        {
            _position = this.Encoding.GetPreamble().Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pos = new List<long>();
        using (var writer = new PositionableStreamWriter("tst.txt", false, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            pos.Add(writer.Position);
            writer.Write("abcde");
            pos.Add(writer.Position);
            writer.WriteLine("Nope");
            pos.Add(writer.Position);
            writer.WriteLine("Something");
            pos.Add(writer.Position);
            writer.WriteLine("Another thing");
            pos.Add(writer.Position);
        }

        using (var stream = File.Open("tst.txt", FileMode.Open))
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pos.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                stream.Position = pos[i];
                var len = (int)(pos[i + 1] - pos[i]);
                var buf = reader.ReadBytes(len);
                Console.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buf));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well thanks for the quick downvote. Anyway updated with the counterpart, positionable stream writer that I think will solve OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a subclass that counts the output characters. According to this [Inheriting from StreamWriter with smallest possible effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266986/inheriting-from-streamwriter-with-smallest-possible-effort) , you only need to override `void Write(Char)`

```
 class StreamWriterWithPosition : StreamWriter {
   override void Write(Char c) { pos += Encoding.GetByteCount(c.ToString()); base.Write(c);}
   int pos = 0;
 }
```

(not tested!)

Comment: That won't work because it doesn't take the encoding into account. For example, if the file is encoded with UTF8 a single character could take up up to 4 bytes.

Comment: As mishel indicates counting characters does not equate to bytes in a stream. Furthermore, since "Write(String s)" will under the hood call "Write(Char[] ca, Int32 offset, Int32 len)" there is another problem that requires solving.